# Importing SSL certificates in Glassfish Application Server

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, netbeans-8, glassfish-4

I am trying to enable SSL on a project on Netbeans IDE and using Glassfish application Server.

For the SSL; i followed the procedure below.

1. Generated a keystore > `keytool -genkey -alias client_keystore -keyalg RSA -keystore client_keystore.jks -keysize 2048`
2. Generated a CSR > `keytool -certreq -alias client_keystore -file yourcsrname.csr -keystore client_keystore.jks`
3. Submitted the CSR to another party.
4. Received three .pem certificates from the party. I converted the .pem to .crt as `openssl x509 -outform der -in your-cert.pem -out your-cert.crt`
5. Importing the certs to my keystore as below;

`keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias intermediate  -file GoDaddy_Intermediate.crt -keystore client_keystore.jks`

`keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file GoDaddy_Root.crt -keystore client_keystore.jks`

`keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias BizSwitch -file BizSwitch.crt -keystore client_keystore.jks`

6. Import the keystore to the default glassfish keystore >`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore ~/Downloads/ipay/client_keystore.jks -destkeystore keystore.jks`
7. Restarted glassfish server.

I am not sure if that's all but I am getting the `sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target` exception.

On restarting, from the glassfish logs I do not see the certificates being loaded as well.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Is your keystore in the folder /domains/domain1/config?

Looks like glassfish does not point to the correct keystore, as you correctly imported the certs.

Comment: Yes, the keystore is in /configs directory.   ....I can not get around why it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Yous should also import the cert into the JVM's truststore...

Reference:
[Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore#9619478)

Answer (score 0):

You created the keypair entry under alias `client_keystore` so you need to import your server cert *to that alias and entry*. Assuming BizSwitch is your server's name, you need to `-importcert -file BizSwitch.crt -alias client_keystore -keystore client_keystore.jks`. If you get it correct the output from that command should be `Certificate reply was installed` NOT `Certificate was added`. (The latter is correct for separate *CA* certs, but not the server cert.)

Also, you didn't need to convert to DER. `keytool` (or more exactly `CertificateFactory`) has been able to read PEM certs for more than a decade, and even PEM-with-comments since j7 circa 2012. (This is not the case for some *other* crypto objects like private keys.)